# DI with Ninject in a Class Library

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject

I'm successfully using Ninject in my web applications by deriving my Global from `NinjectHttpApplication` and using the `NinjectHttpModule` in my web.config

What I want to do now is using DI in one of my class libraries and I don't know how to go about this.  I have the following dummy class:

```c#
/// <summary>
/// Testing Ninject DI in a class library
/// </summary>
public class Class1
{
    [Inject]
    ICustomerRepository CustomerRepository { get; set; }

    public string SomeText { get; set; }

    public Class1(string text)
    {
        MyConfig config = new MyConfig();
        config.Configure();

        SomeText = text;
    }

    public Customer GetCustomer()
    {
        var customer = CustomerRepository.GetCustomer();
        return customer;
    }
}

public class MyConfig
{
    public IKernel Configure()
    {
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new NinjectRepositoryModule());
        return kernel;
    }
}
```

When I instantiate `Class1` and call `GetCustomer()`, the `CustomerRepository` is null, so I'm obviously doing something wrong.

Also, if I use constructor injection and have my constructor like

```c#
public Class1([Inject] ICustomerRepository repository)
```

how would I go about instantiating `Class1`?

Quite new to Ninject, so this could all be very easy stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I already know how to do this - whoops :)

[Ninject - how and when to inject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294779/ninject-how-and-when-to-inject)

Comment: Now that's funny