# How do I create a factory that returns different instances with different parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, ninject, factory

I'm using `ASP.NET MVC` with `Ninject` and I'm trying to create an `ActionResult` factory. Let's say I have the following `ActionResults`:

```
public class SuccessResult : ActionResult
{
    public string SuccessMessage { get; set; }

    public SuccessResult(string successMessage) { ... }
}

public class FailResult : ActionResult
{
    public int FailCode { get; set; }

    public FailResult(int failCode) { ... }
}

public class DataResult : ActionResult
{
    public object Data { get; set; }
    public string MimeType { get; set; }

    public DataResult(object dataToSerialize, string mimeType) { ... }
}
```

So for each `ActionResult`, the parameter types and number of parameters will be different. I created an `ActionResultFactory` that looks like this:

```
public class ActionResultFactory
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;

    public ActionResultFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
    }

    public T Create<T>() where T : ActionResult
    {
        return _kernel.Get<T>(); // how do I pass the parameters?
    }
}
```

How would I write the factory so that it can take parameters and pass them to the object's constructor? Or should I do it like this instead:

```
var result = factory.Create<SuccessResult>();
result.SuccessMessage = "Success!";

var result = factory.Create<FailResult>();
result.FailCode = 404;

var result = factory.Create<DataResult>();
result.Data = file;
result.MimeType = "text/plain";
```

where each property is publically exposed and I assign them after object creation?

Comment: Where is your parameter? Do you mean `T`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 3 Create methods one for each type, pass the required arguments and create the instance like this.

```
public FailResult CreateFailResult(int failcode)
{
    return _kernel.Get<FailResult>(new ConstructorArgument("failCode", failcode));
}
```

Comment: Not a big fan of this solution, but I don't see any other way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You need a Constructor injection with parameters.

Please see below link

[Ninject with parameters](http://kohari.org/2008/03/12/ninject-lives/)

Comment: Ninject 2 doesn't seem to have `With.Parameters`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public T Create<T>(params object[] parameters) 
{
    T instance = _kernel.Get<T>();
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(FailResult))
    {
        FailResult result = (FailResult)instance;
        result.ErrorCode = (int)parameters[0];
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, it seems that I misunderstood OP's question. Oh my poor English!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a little provider to new up and initialize the ActionResult objects for you. Explained here:

See [Creating an instance using Ninject with additional parameters in the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227548/creating-an-instance-using-ninject-with-additional-parameters-in-the-constructor)