# Ninject constructor argument

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject

I have this interface:

```
public interface IUserProfileService
{
    // stuff
}
```

Implemented by:

```
public class UserProfileService : IUserProfileService
{
    private readonly string m_userName;

    public UserProfileService(string userName)
    {
        m_userName = userName;
    }
}
```

I need this injected into a controller like this:

```
public class ProfilesController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IUserProfileService m_profileService;

    public ProfilesController(IUserProfileService profileService)
    {
        m_profileService = profileService;
    }
}
```

I don't know how I can register this interface and its implementation into Ninject container so that userName param is passed in when the Ninject inits an instance of this service.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: I'm in general agreement with what Mike described. For a bit more detail and explanation I'd recommend reading Ruben Bartelink's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227548/creating-an-instance-using-ninject-with-additional-parameters-in-the-constructor. This is a very thorough answer for what you're looking to achieve.

Comment: Can someone explain why they down-voted this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One alternative is to inject a factory and create your dependency using `Create(string userName)`.

```
public class UserProfileServiceFactory
{
    public IUserProfileService Create(string userName)
    {
        return new UserProfileService(userName);
    }
}
```

It might seem off to have to create another class but the benefits mostly comes when `UserProfileService` takes in additional dependencies.

Comment: Would the ProfilesController constructor then take a UserProfileServiceFactory and a userName?

Answer (score 5):

The technical ninject answer is to use constructor arguments like so:

```
Bind<IUserProfileService>().To<UserProfileService>().WithConstructorArgument("userName", "karl");
```

Of course you need to figure out where "karl" comes from. It really depends on your app. Maybe its a web app and it's on the HttpContex? I don't know. If it gets rather complicated then you might want to write a IProvider rather than doing a regular binding.

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to *not* inject the username in that class. You call this class a *service* so it would probably work transparantly with multiple users. I see two solutions:

1. Inject an abstraction into the service that represents the current user:

   ```
   public class UserProfileService : IUserProfileService
   {
       private readonly IPrincipal currentUser;

       public UserProfileService(IPrincipal currentUser)
       {
           this.currentUser = currentUser;
       }

       void IUserProfileService.SomeOperation()
       {
           var user = this.currentUser;

           // Do some nice stuff with user
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create an implementation  that is specific to the technology you are working with, for instance:

   ```
   public class AspNetUserProfileService : IUserProfileService
   {
       public AspNetUserProfileService()
       {
       }

       void IUserProfileService.SomeOperation()
       {
           var user = this.CurrentUser;

           // Do some nice stuff with user
       }

       private IPrincipal CurrentUser
       {
           get { return HttpContext.Current.User; }
       }
   }
   ```

If you can, go with option one.

Comment: On option one, assuming IPrincipal's concrete constructor takes a userName argument, how does this option help?