# Using Ninject for Type Activation

Tags: c#, ninject, activator

Is there any method built-in to Ninject which allows for dynamic instantiation of any given type given its assembly-qualified name (without the need to bind the types manually in a custom `NinjectModule`)?

I could of course use `Activator.CreateInstance` but since I am already using Ninject I would prefer sticking to it rather than using this method (which I heard may be pretty slow, by the way).

Comment: Is this of any use? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227548/creating-an-instance-using-ninject-with-additional-parameters-in-the-constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ninject needs to have bindings to create instances. These bindings can either be created statically or using conventions. Depending on what you want to do, conventions might be what you need. Have a look at Ninject.Extensions.Conventions.

Answer (score 2):

You could use below, which will look for all classes which extend NinjectModule in a given assembly and load them:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Load(Assembly.Load("assembly.dll"));
```