# Binding recurring connection string constructor parameters using DI

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I'm looking for advice on how best to bind a couple of connection 
strings which recur throughout my dependencies.

Currently I have (using ninject):

```
Bind<IFoo>().To<SqlFoo>()
.WithConstructorArgument("db1ConnStr", db1ConnectionString)
.WithConstructorArgument("db2ConnStr", db2ConnectionString);

Bind<IBar>().To<SqlBar>()
.WithConstructorArgument("db1ConnStr", db1ConnectionString)
.WithConstructorArgument("db2ConnStr", db2ConnectionString);
```

etc.

which obviously is not the most elegant code.

Is there a way to bind the value of db1ConnectionString to every string constructor parameter named "db1ConnStr"?

Comment: Where did the initial version of this go? Could have sworn I saw and effectively gave the same answer to this in the last few days? - ah found it https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ninject/gZErCEzCBgU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a class which holds the connection strings:

```
public class ConnectionStringProvider
{
    public string Db1ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public string Db2ConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

Note: You can also create an interface `IConnectionStringProvider` for it if you want.

Then the classes `SqlFoo` and `SqlBar` can use it as a dependency

```
public class SqlFoo
{
    public SqlFoo(ConnectionStringProvider connectionStringProvider)
    {
         //do something with connectionStringProvider.Db1ConnectionString 
    }
}
```

And the registration would look like this:

```
Bind<ConnectionStringProvider>().ToConstant(
    new ConnectionStringProvider
    {
        Db1ConnectionString = db1ConnectionString,
        Db2ConnectionString = db2ConnectionString,
    });
Bind<IFoo>().To<SqlFoo>();
Bind<IBar>().To<SqlBar>();
```