# How to pass parameter to constructor with Ninject

Tags: c#, .net, ninject

I tried for two days examples of how to pass a value to the constructor of a class board using Ninject. I have seen many examples, but I did not understand much. Especially I would like to see, as well as recording the configuration of the building (Bind) as well as passing a value at run-time:

```
    _Kernel.Get(of MyRoot)(Pass. "TheValue". At.param. "Param1". For(of INdependency))
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227548/creating-an-instance-using-ninject-with-additional-parameters-in-the-constructor

Answer (score 2):

You may try to use .WithConstructorArgument.